# MoveToElement - RemoteWebDriver threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using code below for move to element, but actionExecutor returns an exception.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(link_text));
Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
ac.MoveToElement(element);
ac.Build().Perform();
```

[image]

I received comment that "This is not a valid endpoint for w3c, and is no longer supported by Chrome."
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10344

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem with the MoveToElement method, please?

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? If the major versions do not match, you need to download the version of ChromeDriver to match the Chrome version. For example, if you have Chrome v99.x, you need to be running ChromeDriver v99.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you move to the element you must check if you actually found it:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.
LinkText(link_text));
if (element!=null) {
   Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
   ac.MoveToElement(element);
   ac.Perform();
}
```

Note that you can remove the `Build()` call, as you are doing only a single action and not more.

If the element you found is indeed null, try to find it by `Xpath` or `CSS` and not by LinkText.